# Spring boot with data jpa - delete entity only works on tests

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, rest-assured

I'm strugling with this problem for too long, its time to ask devs community.

**==Short Description==**

Using Spring data JPA, i'm unable to delete my entity from my `Controller`, no exceptions is being thrown.
If i try to call `.delete()` from `IntegrationTest class`, it works.

**==My Enviroment==**

- Java 8
- Spring Boot 1.5.1
- Spring Data JPA 1.11.0
- RestAssured 2.9.0

**CartItemSecRest.java - My Controller method (NOT WORKING)**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/secure/carts/{id}/items")
public class CartItemSecRest
{
    @DeleteMapping("{itemId}")
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
    public void delete(@PathVariable("id") CartSession cartSession, @PathVariable("itemId") CartItemSession cartItemSession, @AuthenticationPrincipal JwtUser jwtUser){

        // checking permission and so on..

        if (cartItemSession == null || cartSession == null)
            throw new BaseException.EntityNotFound();

        if(cartSession.getUser().getId() != jwtUser.getId())
            throw new BaseException.Forbidden();

        cartItemService.delete(cartItemSession);
    }
}
```

**=== INTEGRATION TEST SIDE ===**

During Integration test, i use In-memory DB.
Before each Test, i'm creating(saving to DB) new User with Cart containing 3 CartItem.

My Integration Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class CartItemSecRestIT extends BaseEcommerceRestIT
{
    //Other test methods

    /**
     * Logged user, try to remove item from cart.
     */
    @Test
    public void deleteCartItem()
    {
        CartItemSession cartItemSession = cartSession.getItems().get(0);
        requestWithAuthToken(user)
                .delete(String.format("api/secure/carts/%s/items/%s", cartSession.getId(), cartItemSession.getId()))
                .then()
                .statusCode(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT.value());

        List<CartItemSession> actualCartItems = cartItemManager.findBySessionId(cartSession.getId());
        assertEquals(2, actualCartItems.size());
    }
}
```

The assertion fails with always same error, seems no item was deleted.

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected :2
Actual   :3

at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
...
at yyyy.xxx.api.rest.secure.CartItemSecRestIT.deleteCartItem(CartItemSecRestIT.java:179)
```

The strange behaviour, in IntegrationClass, whenever i call:

- cartItemService.delete(xx);
- cartItemManager.delete(xx);
- cartItemRepository.delete(xx);

its working as expected, the item is deleted.

in fact, if i write the following integration test method, everything looks ok ! (test turns green)

```
@Test
public void deleteTestOK()
{
    //lets test with Manager
    List<CartItemSession> cartItemSessions = cartItemManager.findBySessionId(cartSession.getId());
    cartItemManager.delete(cartItemSessions.get(0).getId());
    assertEquals(2, cartItemManager.findBySessionId(cartSession.getId()).size());

    //test with service
    cartItemSessions = cartItemManager.findBySessionId(cartSession.getId());
    cartItemService.delete(cartItemSessions.get(0));
    assertEquals(1, cartItemManager.findBySessionId(cartSession.getId()).size());

    //test with repository
    cartItemSessions = cartItemManager.findBySessionId(cartSession.getId());
    cartItemRepository.delete(cartItemSessions.get(0));
    assertEquals(0, cartItemManager.findBySessionId(cartSession.getId()).size());
}
```

If i try the same thing on "server-side" (Controller), none of these delete methods works.

```
@DeleteMapping("{itemId}")
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") CartSession cartSession, @PathVariable("itemId") CartItemSession cartItemSession, @AuthenticationPrincipal JwtUser jwtUser){

    //Check permission and so on

    if (cartItemSession == null || cartSession == null)
        throw new BaseException.EntityNotFound();

    if(cartSession.getUser().getId() != jwtUser.getId())
        throw new BaseException.Forbidden();

    //try using repository
    cartItemRepository.delete(cartItemSession);
    logger.info("1° delete - total items: {}", cartItemManager.count());

    //try using service
    cartItemService.delete(cartItemSession);
    logger.info("2° delete - total items: {}", cartItemManager.count());

    //try using manager
    cartItemManager.delete(cartItemSession);
    logger.info("3° delete - total items: {}", cartItemManager.count());
}
```

But the output says that no items has been deleted !

```
1° delete - total items: 3
2° delete - total items: 3
3° delete - total items: 3
```

I can't find whats wrong on controller class.

**======= UPDATE 13/05/2017 =======**

I found a way to make it works, but no reasonable explanation:

Ok, i'm close to the point, look at this:

This is my "EcCartSession":

```
public class EcCartSession{
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)//THIS IS THE IMPORTANT ONE
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = AbstractItemSession.class, mappedBy = "session", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<EcCartItemSession> items = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

**WORKING:**

```
public void delete(@PathVariable("itemId") EcCartItemSession cartItemSession, @AuthenticationPrincipal JwtUser jwtUser){
    cartItemService.delete(cartItemSession);
}
```

**NOT WORKING:**

```
public void delete(@PathVariable("id") EcCartSession cartSession, @PathVariable("itemId") EcCartItemSession cartItemSession, @AuthenticationPrincipal JwtUser jwtUser){
    cartItemService.delete(cartItemSession);
}
```

Instead, if i put `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)`

it works on both case.

**======= UPDATE 31/05/2017 =======**

Enabled logging for transaction package on my `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.transaction=TRACE
```

Running again integration tests, this is the output generated just after calling `cartItemService.delete(cartItemSession)` (controller):

```
2017-05-31 00:21:18.479 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@640f8a5f] for key [public abstract void org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.delete(java.lang.Object)] to thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.481 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@2a0c8406] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] bound to thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.486 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4c417bab] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@19c1d60a{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=org.h2.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:h2:mem:webproject;;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; username=sa; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }] to thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.487 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2017-05-31 00:21:18.487 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.488 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@2a0c8406] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] bound to thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.488 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@2a0c8406] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] bound to thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.493 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.delete]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.497 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2017-05-31 00:21:18.503 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@4c417bab] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@19c1d60a{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=org.h2.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:h2:mem:webproject;;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; username=sa; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }] from thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:18.503 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@640f8a5f] for key [public abstract void org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.delete(java.lang.Object)] from thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.380 TRACE 22924 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@2a0c8406] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] from thread [http-nio-auto-1-exec-1]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.881 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@52a1d6f] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@19c1d60a{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=org.h2.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:h2:mem:webproject;;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; username=sa; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }] to thread [main]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.881 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@38bb297] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] to thread [main]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.881 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Initializing transaction synchronization
2017-05-31 00:21:23.881 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [org.domain.ecommerce.core.data.managers.spring.CartItemManagerImpl.findBySessionId]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.882 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Bound value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@6c96e1d5] for key [public abstract java.util.List org.domain.core.data.repositories.jpa.SessionItemRepository.findBySessionId(java.io.Serializable)] to thread [main]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.882 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Don't need to create transaction for [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findBySessionId]: This method isn't transactional.
2017-05-31 00:21:23.882 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@38bb297] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] bound to thread [main]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.886 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@38bb297] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] bound to thread [main]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.893 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$DefaultCrudMethodMetadata@6c96e1d5] for key [public abstract java.util.List org.domain.core.data.repositories.jpa.SessionItemRepository.findBySessionId(java.io.Serializable)] from thread [main]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.893 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [org.domain.ecommerce.core.data.managers.spring.CartItemManagerImpl.findBySessionId]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.894 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Clearing transaction synchronization
2017-05-31 00:21:23.894 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder@38bb297] for key [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean@603bc676] from thread [main]
2017-05-31 00:21:23.894 TRACE 22924 --- [           main] .s.t.s.TransactionSynchronizationManager : Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@52a1d6f] for key [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource@19c1d60a{ConnectionPool[defaultAutoCommit=null; defaultReadOnly=null; defaultTransactionIsolation=-1; defaultCatalog=null; driverClassName=org.h2.Driver; maxActive=100; maxIdle=100; minIdle=10; initialSize=10; maxWait=30000; testOnBorrow=true; testOnReturn=false; timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=5000; numTestsPerEvictionRun=0; minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=60000; testWhileIdle=false; testOnConnect=false; password=********; url=jdbc:h2:mem:webproject;;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE; username=sa; validationQuery=SELECT 1; validationQueryTimeout=-1; validatorClassName=null; validationInterval=3000; accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed=true; removeAbandoned=false; removeAbandonedTimeout=60; logAbandoned=false; connectionProperties=null; initSQL=null; jdbcInterceptors=null; jmxEnabled=true; fairQueue=true; useEquals=true; abandonWhenPercentageFull=0; maxAge=0; useLock=false; dataSource=null; dataSourceJNDI=null; suspectTimeout=0; alternateUsernameAllowed=false; commitOnReturn=false; rollbackOnReturn=false; useDisposableConnectionFacade=true; logValidationErrors=false; propagateInterruptState=false; ignoreExceptionOnPreLoad=false; }] from thread [main]
```

Comment: Add also code of the cartItemService to show how transaction is started

Comment: Did you check, if `testItem` is not null before trying to delete it?

Comment: code added/updated

Comment: I do not see any @Transactional on your service. Could you add it and check the behaviour ?

Comment: @willome : according to [Spring Data Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions) "CRUD methods on repository instances are transactional by default", btw i tried placing `@Transactional` annotation, but same results.

Comment: Turn on TRACE logging for org.springframework.transaction.interceptor and post your logs around the time of the delete call.